# SwiftUI - Prevent TextField from expanding when text is entered

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `TextField` with a fixed-size frame, but it still expands to wrap the entered text, even over siblings.

**Initial state:**

[image: Initial TextField]

**With some input:**

[image: TextField with input]

Is there a way to prevent this in SwiftUI using `TextField` or do I need to resort to ViewRepresentable?

My code for this layout looks something like:

```swift
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("1").fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false).frame(width: 22)
    TextField("Price", text: $text1).fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false).frame(width: 70)
    TextField("1", text: $text2).fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false).frame(width: 30)
    TextField("1", text: $text3).fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false).frame(width: 70)
}.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change order of modifiers, like

```
TextField("1", text: $text3)
   .frame(width: 70)                                // << here !!
   .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore on iOS16 and iOS17. Text is running out of the view again while editing